# Matlab: find diagonal neighbors

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of size (H, W), and I need to have a 2xP output with all diagonal neighbords of the matrix, i.e. for every (i,j) pair have [(i,j); (i-1,j-1)] and [(i,j); (i-1,j+1)] pairs (only 2 pairs, not 4, as I don't need the duplicated neighboors pairs).

Each element of the matrix is just its index in the matrix.

I tried it brute-force (tried only for points for which both neighbors like this exist):

```
coord = reshape(1:w*h, h, w);
pairs = [];
for i=2:h-1
    for j=2:w-1
        pairs = [pairs [coord(i,j) coord(i, j); coord(i-1,j-1) coord(i-1, j+1)]];
    end
end
```

But it is too slow. What is the smart&fast way to rewrite this code in Matlab? Preferably, including the cases when only one of such neighbors exist (eg. second row & last column: only top-left neighbour exists but not top-right).

For h=w=10 this code gives me (correct, I hope) 128 pairs.

Comment: Preallocating `pairs` would definitely help: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html The size is known in advance.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, it helped indeed. I heard that preallocating helps but really didn't realize how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the already mentioned preallocation, here is a small variation of your algorithm with does what you want:

```
w=4
h=5
coord = reshape(1:w*h, h, w);
pairs = [];
k=1;
pairs=nan(2,(w-1*h-1))
for i=1:h-1
    for j=1:w-1
        pairs(:,k:k+1)=[coord(i+1,j+1) coord(i+1, j); coord(i,j) coord(i, j+1)];
        k=k+2;
    end
end
```

Your idea was to insert the neighbors for a given element (`coord(i,j)`). A small variation and you no longer have the corner cases. Insert the two neighbor relations which are within a square of four elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize your code.

The following code takes your for loop indices and, place each one in separate matrix:

```
A = (coord(2:end-1, 2:end-1))'; %coord(i,j)
B = A;                          %coord(i,j)
C = (coord(1:end-2, 1:end-2))'; %coord(i-1,j-1)
D = (coord(1:end-2, 3:end))';   %coord(i-1,j+1)
```

The following part interweave the data in the desired format:

```
P = zeros(2, (w-2)*(h-2)*2);
P(1, 1:2:end) = A(:);
P(1, 2:2:end) = B(:);
P(2, 1:2:end) = C(:);
P(2, 2:2:end) = D(:);
```

---

Here is a complete working (test) code sample:

```
h = 10;
w = 10;

coord = reshape(1:w*h, h, w);

%Original loop (kept for testing).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
pairs = [];
for i=2:h-1
    for j=2:w-1
        pairs = [pairs [coord(i,j) coord(i, j); coord(i-1,j-1) coord(i-1, j+1)]];
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

A = (coord(2:end-1, 2:end-1))'; %coord(i,j)
B = A;                          %coord(i,j)
C = (coord(1:end-2, 1:end-2))'; %coord(i-1,j-1)
D = (coord(1:end-2, 3:end))';   %coord(i-1,j+1)

P = zeros(2, (w-2)*(h-2)*2);
P(1, 1:2:end) = A(:);
P(1, 2:2:end) = B(:);
P(2, 1:2:end) = C(:);
P(2, 2:2:end) = D(:);

%Verify result is the same:  
isequal(P, pairs)
```

---

Here is a more compact solution:

```
P = zeros(2, (w-2)*(h-2)*2);
P(1, 1:2:end) = reshape(coord(2:end-1, 2:end-1)', 1, (w-2)*(h-2));    %coord(i,j)
P(1, 2:2:end) = P(1, 1:2:end);                                        %coord(i,j)
P(2, 1:2:end) = reshape((coord(1:end-2, 1:end-2))', 1, (w-2)*(h-2));  %coord(i-1,j-1)
P(2, 2:2:end) = reshape((coord(1:end-2, 3:end))', 1, (w-2)*(h-2));    %coord(i-1,j+1)
```